# Call the added file in Hive to use for UDF

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, hdfs, user-defined-functions

I have a file which contains holidays and it is required by UDF to use this file to run and calculate the given business days for two dates. Issue I have is when I add the file, it goes to a working directory but this directory differs every session.

Unlike in the example below from [Hive Resources](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveResources) - This is not what is happening.

```
  hive> add FILE /tmp/tt.py;
  hive> list FILES;
  /tmp/tt.py
  hive> select from networks a 
               MAP a.networkid 
               USING 'python tt.py' as nn where a.ds = '2009-01-04' limit 10;
```

This is what I am getting and the alpha numeric keeps changing.
/mnt/tmp/**a17b43d5-df53-4eea-8e2c-565471b49d25_resources**/holiday2021.csv

I need to make this file located in a more permanent folder and this hive sql can be executed into any of the 18 nodes.

Comment: why not to create table and join with it?

Comment: Looping in-memory is faster than doing a join especially with big volume data. That's my assumption. Programmer who built this left the company already.

Comment: If you can load file in memory in your mapper, then you can perform map-join in memory, it can be configured, if you cant load it in memory, this will not help also,

Comment: Using `add FILE` should add the file into the distributed cache, and so the specific location into which it's stored shouldn't matter. You should be able to access it just via the file name. Are you sure you can't access it in the same way as in the example?